# What parameters to check to say that a computer running Windows is slow in responding because of infection?

Tags: malware, operating-systems

When interaction between the user and the operating system is too slow (Windows become slow in responding to different user's request): what parameters could we check (and that we could use within a program coded in any programming language) in order to say for sure that the computer running this Windows operating system is maybe infected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this interesting patent titled "[Network-based infection detection using host slowdown](https://www.google.com/patents/US8166544)"

I quote from the abstract of this patent:

> Host malware (or change) may be detected by (1) receiving baseline set of response time information for each of one or more transactions involving (A) the host and (B) at least one peer of the host, (2) determining or receiving a later set of response time information for each of the one or more transactions involving the host and the at least one peer of the host, and (3) determining whether or not host slowdown has occurred using the baseline set of response time information and the later set of response time information. The execution of a host malware (or change) protection policy may be controlled using at least the determination of whether or not host slowdown has occurred.